# How can I convert Grease Pencil's 'Build' modifier to keyframes?

Tags: keyframes, grease-pencil

I am completely new to blender and started to learn it for 2D animation purposes.

I experimented with the grease pencil modifier "Build" but I can't figure out how to convert the animated sequence into keyframes.

I would like to have every stroke converted to keyframes in order to adjust the timing of it, remove/add lines etc. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

In Blender 2.93 you can do just that with the "Use Factor" parameter in the Build modifier properties. You can set (and animate) the parameter with values ranging from 0.000 (beginning of the stroke) to 1.000 (fully drawn stroke).

Answer (score 0):

You can divide the various strokes into layers, then add more than a build modifier, targeting each one to a single layer. Then every build modifier can be set to start at one certain frame and last for any number of frames.

Comment: Do you mean to create a new layer each time I draw a line or something else ?

Comment: Create a new layer each time you want a different layer of animation start and timing.

Comment: Or, without the build modifier, you can use the "standard" functions of Grease Pencil, in which you make some strokes, then change frame, then copy the first keyframe and edit it, and so on. In this way every drawing is on one keyframe, which can be manipulated, and there are also advanced  interpolation functions.

Comment: The first option sounds more interesting than the second one.
The goal is to find a way to gain time over traditional animation (which is the second solution you offers).
I guess it can only work for simple drawing.

Comment: So is there a way to export the "build" animation into an edible format that I can then re-import into blender ? or to make some kind of precomps ?

Comment: The only way I can think of is exporting an image sequence, but I don't think it's an useful way.

Comment: Today I try to find my way around a little bit more...and I found 2 fonctions the first one (on the top left side of the screen) wich is a snow icon says : Use Additive Drawing.
Is there a way to stay on the same layer and to apply the build modifier on every frames (in a way that only the last stroke get the build modifier) ?

Comment: then I saw that there is a graph editor, is there a way to make easy ease (or any time/speed tweeks) to grease pencil modifier ?

Comment: For the first question, I would use Layers (that you can copy, paste, restrict and whatever). Without them there's no built-in function ASAIK. This lead to the second: short answer: No!  If you need not build-in functions, you have to create some Pythoon code, but I'm not able to help you on this side.

Comment: Thank you Josh !